# how to compare and filteredout data with next array special characters string reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

here is my question how to categorize the array data with the help of other array data elements
im confusing how to compare the two array data sets with the common value

how can i access the animal# in `referenceBasedValues` and how to compare with `referenceData` elements

```
 const referenceData = ['animal#', 'flower#' , 'Cats#', 'dogs/colorDogs/']

    const referenceBasedValues = [{ref : 'animal#cow', value : 'Cow'},
                  {ref : 'animal#pig', value : 'Pig'},
                  {ref : 'animal#hourse', value : 'Hourse'},
                  {ref : 'flower#rose', value : 'Rose'},
                  {ref : 'flower#leafRose', value : 'Leaf Rose'},
                  {ref : 'Cats#bigcat', value : 'Big cat'},
                  {ref : 'Cats#smallcat', value : 'Small Cat'},
                  {ref : 'dogs/colorDogs/whiteDog', value : 'White dog'},
                  {ref : 'dogs/colorDogs/BlackDog', value : 'Black dog'},]
```

> Im expecting the output like this

```
  const finalData = [{reference : 'animal#' , values :['Cow' , 'Pig' ,'Hourse']},
                     {reference : 'flower#' , values :['Rose' , 'Leaf Rose' ,'Hourse']},
                     {reference : 'Cats#' , values :['Big cat' , 'Small Cat']},
                     {reference : 'dogs/colorDogs/' , values :['White dog','Black dog']}
                    ]
```

im able to accesing `animal#, flower#, Cats#` with `substring(0 , referenceData[i].reference.lastIndexOf("#"))`

but im not able to accessing `dogs/colorDogs/` word in array while filtering

**If any one give answer for this one so appreciatable**

Answer (score 1):

// v1

```js
const finalData = referenceData.map(reference => {
  const re = new RegExp('^' + reference);
  const values = referenceBasedValues.filter(base => re.test(base.ref)).map(base => base.value);
  return {
    reference,
    values,
  };
});
```

// v2

```js
const re = new RegExp(`^(${referenceData.join('|')})`);
const finalData = Object.entries(referenceBasedValues.reduce((obj, { ref, value }) => {
  const match = re.exec(ref);
  if (match) {
    let key = match[0];
    obj[key] ??= [];
    obj[key].push(value);
  }
  return obj;
}, {})).map(([reference, values]) => ({ reference, values }));
```